# Getting Piranha CMS working with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, piranha-cms

I'm quite interested in Piranha, but unfortunately getting it up and running following [these instructions](http://piranhacms.org/docs/introduction/getting-started) is frustrating.

When I follow these instructions (I tried 3 times) and run the site I just get "The resource cannot be found".

From the routing supplied it's clearly looking for `/Home/Index`, but that's not as part of the solution. I added the Home controller, but by itself it does nothing. Browsing to `/Page/Index` results in "The resource cannot be found" too.

I'm supposed to see an installation screen, but where is it?

Comment: Also, in the instructions it says I should get a dialog saying "App_Start\RouteConfig.cs" already exists, but there was no such dialog.

Comment: OK, doing the "Creating a new ASP.NET Web Pages website" steps (only one step really) it worked first time. I need it to work with MVC though, not web forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to reproduce the error when creating an new Web application > MVC > Empty in Visual Studio 2013. Creating an empty MVC application in Visual Studio 2012 does not produce the same result.

Opening the project created in VS2012 in VS2013, recompiling it and running it doesn't produce the same error so there's obviously something different in how the projects are created which I'll have to look into.

Can you confirm that you are using VS2013?

Comment: If you're running VS2013 have the VS2012 templates available inside of VS2013 you can use these and create an Piranha CMS MVC application until I figure out the difference between the VS2013 Web application template and the VS2012 MVC4 Application template. The templates are usually located beneath Visual C# > Web > Visual Studio 2012

Comment: I've created an issue for this at the GitHub repo https://github.com/tidyui/Piranha/issues/203

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! I'm using VS2012. It looks like there's some controller stuff missing perhaps, but I can't be sure. Or do I need 2013 to make it run?

Comment: The steps I'm taking is as follows:
1. Open VS2102
2. File > New > Project
3. Under Web, ASP.NET MVC4 Web Application
4. Empty Template, Razor engine
5. From Package Manager Console, run Install-Package PiranhaCMSMvc
6. After it completes run
7. Magically it works all of a sudden, though I can't see what has changed.

Did you change the nuget package in the last few hours :o)

BTW, thanks, I can't wait to get playing with it!

Comment: Hi there! No I haven't published a new package. The current package was built for VS2012 so that's why I hadn't tested it with the new VS2013 templates. So you don't need to install that. Happy that you got it working!

Comment: @BenPower: Really weird. I'm using VS2012. 1: Install PiranhaCMSMvc, failed. 2: Install PiranhaCMS, failed. 3: Install PiranhaCMSMvc, and... it just worked?!?!

Comment: @Kabie, yes, that was similar to my experience. It is worth the effort though, it's an excellent little CMS.